# How to create day part in R from a vector of POSIXct timestamps?

Tags: r, timestamp, posixct

I have a long series of POSIXct timestamps. I would like to return, for each record a day part, including day of the week. 
For example:

```
[1] Sunday night
[2] Sunday night
[3] Sunday afternoon
[4] Saturday night
[5] Sunday afternoon
```

... and so on.

Below is a small sample of the data:

```
my_dates <- as.POSIXct(c("2000-03-12 19:40:00 AEDT",
                            "2000-03-19 17:40:00 AEDT", 
                            "2000-03-26 14:10:00 AEST", 
                            "2000-04-01 19:40:00 AEST", 
                            "2000-04-09 14:10:00 AEST",
                            "2000-04-16 14:40:00 AEST",
                            "2000-04-22 19:40:00 AEST",
                            "2000-04-30 14:10:00 AEST",
                            "2000-05-07 14:10:00 AEST",
                            "2000-05-14 14:10:00 AEST"))
```

I have tried a lot of different things, but I always end up losing the date format.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You will always lose the date format as 'Sunday night' is not a valid date object. It will just end up being a character string.

Comment: I mean, I lose the date format in between operations when converting the original vector of timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some creative `format`ting and `cut`ting should be able to get you there:

```
paste(
  format(my_dates, "%A"),
  c("night","morn","afternoon","night")[
    cut(as.numeric(format(my_dates,"%H")), c(0,5,11,17,23))
  ]
)
# [1] "Sunday night"     "Sunday afternoon" "Sunday afternoon" "Saturday night"  
# [5] "Sunday afternoon" "Sunday afternoon" "Saturday night"   "Sunday afternoon"
# [9] "Sunday afternoon" "Sunday afternoon"
```

Comment: and not to forget the brilliant use of subsetting based on the actual factor value (the integers). That's really amazing. I'd love to upvote this twice.