# How to create a day/night factor from POSIXct variable

Tags: r, time, posixct

I have a data table with a column of POSIXct date/times. I would like to create a column that specifies "day" or "night" based on the POSIXct timestamp. Day is defined in local time as between 05:30:00 and 20:00:00.

I have tried to create the new variable using an ifelse statement based on a column of "time of day" created using strptime, but end up with strange results.

Here is a simple example - setting it up as a data table to match my real dataset.

```
library(data.table)

SightingTime = c("2017-07-31 09:56:27 UTC", "2017-07-31 10:36:30 UTC", "2017-08-01 00:07:20 UTC","2017-08-01 01:31:00 UTC", "2017-08-01 10:38:23 UTC", "2017-08-01 21:13:06 UTC", "2017-08-02 15:13:30 UTC", "2017-08-02 18:05:28 UTC", "2017-08-02 21:04:08 UTC")
x=data.table(SightingTime)
```

First I extract the time of day from the date/time variable - I want this in  local time because I'll specify sunrise/sunset in local time.

```
x$TOD = strftime(x$SightingTime, format="%H:%M:S",tz="America/Halifax")
```

I'm not sure why the new TOD variable is still in UTC even though I specify a different time zone.

Then a try to create a new variable with an ifelse statement

```
x$daynight = with(x,
           ifelse(TOD > 05:30:00 & TOD < 20:00:00, "Day", "Night"))
```

I've clearly got this bit incorrect as I get warning messages AND the results in the "day/night" column do not make sense.

What I'm hoping for is something like this.

```
             SightingTime      TOD daynight
1: 2017-07-31 09:56:27 UTC 06:56:27    Day
2: 2017-07-31 10:36:30 UTC 07:36:30    Day
3: 2017-08-01 00:07:20 UTC 21:07:20    Night
4: 2017-08-01 01:31:00 UTC 22:31:00    Night
5: 2017-08-01 10:38:23 UTC 07:38:23    Day
6: 2017-08-01 21:13:06 UTC 08:13:06    Day
7: 2017-08-02 15:13:30 UTC 12:13:30    Day
8: 2017-08-02 18:05:28 UTC 15:05:28    Day
9: 2017-08-02 21:04:08 UTC 18:04:08    Day
```

Comment: There are more issues than in the linked question. The conversion from character to  `POSIXct` doesn't work, the tz of the character vector seems UTC and needs to be converted, time of day is not extracted correctly and the comparison in `ifelse` doesn't work since `05:30:00` is not a valid format (neither numeric nor character). I wrote an answer that is more complete than the linked one but can't post it now. I think this was closed by mistake...

Comment: @JBGruber My mistake, I reopened. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem. Thanks @Henrik

Comment: Given that you use `data.table`, you may also try the `ITime` class and `between`: `x[ , daynight := c("night", "day")[(as.ITime(SightingTime) %between% as.ITime(c("05:30:00", "20:00:00")) + 1)]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Data

```
library(data.table)

SightingTime_chr = c("2017-07-31 09:56:27 UTC", "2017-07-31 10:36:30 UTC", "2017-08-01 00:07:20 UTC","2017-08-01 01:31:00 UTC", "2017-08-01 10:38:23 UTC", "2017-08-01 21:13:06 UTC", "2017-08-02 15:13:30 UTC", "2017-08-02 18:05:28 UTC", "2017-08-02 21:04:08 UTC")
x = data.table(SightingTime_chr)
```

## Code

A couple of things were not quite right with your conversion to datetime (the format for example):

```
x$SightingTime = as.POSIXct(x$SightingTime_chr, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
attributes(x$SightingTime)$tzone <- "America/Halifax"
```

I would first convert the character strings to `POSIXct` and then convert to the America/Halifax timezone as the original vector seems to be in UTC datetime (omit the second step if I#m wrong).

```
x$TOD <- format(x$SightingTime, format="%H%M%S")

x$daynight = with(x, ifelse(TOD > "053000" & TOD < "200000", "Day", "Night"))
```

I convert the time of day to a pseudo-numeric value (the values are not technically correct but this should be enough for the comparison purpose).

```
x$daynight
[1] "Day"   "Day"   "Night" "Night" "Day"   "Day"   "Day"   "Day"   "Day"
```

Now the results appear correct.

## Alternative

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36464848/how-to-create-day-part-in-r-from-a-vector-of-posixct-timestamps) we can get an elegant solution in case we want mor than just night/day:

```
nightday <- function(datetime) {
  paste(
    c("Night", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Evening", "Night")[
      cut(as.numeric(format(datetime, "%H%M")), c(0, 530, 1100, 1700 ,2000, 2359))
      ]
  )
}
nightday(x$SightingTime)
[1] "Morning"   "Morning"   "Night"     "Night"     "Morning"   "Evening"   "Afternoon" "Afternoon" "Evening"
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it works great. I did look at the solution you linked to, but couldn't figure out how to apply it to my situation because I was using 5:30 as a cutoff instead of whole hours.

Comment: I think this should be fine as you are only looking for morning/night. But I added an alternative answer since I was interested in the answer @Henrik had linked.

Comment: I really like your pseudo-numeric approach. I had never thought of trying to do it that way. It's a nice way to think about it. Thx.

Comment: How would you do this to factor in the change in sunrise and sunset?